# Adding noise to nonlinear ODE system

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, random, nonlinear

I have a problem with adding a noise to 3d order ODE nonlinear system. I solved the system numericaly and got the periodic solution and now I need to add random pertubations. Due to the lack of experience of working with SDE I couldn't get the noisy plot. Here's the code:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
            (******It's all just params******************************)
    δ = 0.5`100;
    κ = 0.7`100;
    α = 0.5`100;
    tl = 270;
    too = 280;
    Ocean = 500;
    Land = 25;
    γ = 2.256`100;
    μ = 0.335`100;
    k = 5100;
    M = 0.9999`100 10^4;
    vo = 0.746326`100 10^(17 - 8/κ);
    a = SetPrecision[(0.1666 k)/((too - tl) γ), 100];
    b = SetPrecision[(δ a (too - tl))/(vo^κ tl), 100];
    p = SetPrecision[a (too - tl), 100];
    c = SetPrecision[1/too (k α - (γ p)), 100];
    α = SetPrecision[(γ p + c too)/k, 10];
    β =SetPrecision[-((γ p - c tl)/((1 - vo^κ/M) k)), 100];
    \[Sigma] = SetPrecision[(δ a β)/(M b), 100];
                (************Computing stability points****************)
bifP = 119;
f[x_, y_, z_] := a δ y - a δ z - b z x^κ /. x -> 10000 x;
g[x_, y_, z_] := (bifP α)/Ocean + (γ a)/Ocean z - (γ a + c)/Ocean y /. x -> 10000 x;     
h[x_, y_, z_] := bifP β/Land - bifP β/(M Land) x^κ + ((γ + δ μ) a)/
     Land y - ((γ + δ μ) a + c)/Land z - (μ b z x^κ)/Land /. x -> 10000 x;
j = Outer[D, {f[x, y, z], g[x, y, z], h[x, y, z]}, {x, y, z}];
odeSystem = {f[x, y, z], g[x, y, z], h[x, y, z]};
SetPrecision[stabilityPoints = Solve[odeSystem == 0, {x, y, z}], 10];
stablePoint = stabilityPoints[[1]]
m = j /. stablePoint;
time = 600;
    (*******Numerical Solution of ODE****************************)
Solution = SetPrecision[
  NDSolve[{v'[t] == a δ to[t] - a δ τ[t] - b τ[t] (10000 v[t])^κ ,
    to'[t] == (bifP α)/Ocean + (γ a)/Ocean τ[t] - (γ a + c)/Ocean to[t],
    τ'[t] == bifP β/Land (1 - (10000 v[t])^κ/M) + ((γ + μ) a)/
    Land to[t] - ((γ + μ) a + c)/Land τ[t] - (b μ)/Land (10000 v[t])^κ τ[t],
    v[0] == x, to[0] == y, τ[0] == z}, {v[t], to[t], τ[t]},
    {t, time}  , Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
    PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 9], 30] /. stablePoint;
                        (***************Plots****************)
Plot[Evaluate[{v[t], to[t], τ[t]} /. Solution], {t, 0, time}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Green, Thick}, {Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}}, 
    FrameLabel -> {Style["t", 16, Italic], 
    Style[Row[{Style["x", Italic], ", ", Style["y", 16, Italic]}], 16]}, 
    Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    PlotPoints -> time, ImageSize -> .9 400 {1, 1}, 
    ImagePadding -> {{40, Automatic}, {40, Automatic}}]

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{v[t], τ[t], to[t]} /. Solution], {t, 0, time}, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> Automatic,
    PlotStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> 300 , PlotPoints -> time, 
    AxesLabel -> {Style["V", Large], Style["Tl", Large], 
    Style["To", Large], ImageSize -> 500, Axes -> True}] 
(***The same system but with random pertubations, white noize precisely**)
sigma = 1
trajectory = ItoProcess[{
  \[DifferentialD] v[t] == (a*δ*to[t] - a*δ*τ[t] - b*τ[t]*(10000 v[t])^κ )
     \[DifferentialD] t + sigma \[DifferentialD] w[t],
  \[DifferentialD] to[t] == ((bifP*α)/Ocean + (γ*a)/Ocean τ[t] - (γ*a + c)/Ocean to[t] )
     \[DifferentialD] t + sigma \[DifferentialD] w[t], 
  \[DifferentialD] τ[t] == (bifP β/Land*(1 - (10000 v[t])^κ/M) + ((γ + μ)*a)/
     Land to[t] - ((γ + μ)*a + c)/Land τ[t] - (b*μ)/Land (10000 v[t])^κ*τ[t]) 
     \[DifferentialD] t + sigma \[DifferentialD] w[t]},
  { v[t], to[t], τ[t]}, {{v, to, τ}, {x, y, z}}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]
RandomFunction[trajectory, {0, 100, 1}];
ListLinePlot[%, Filling -> Axis]
```

Comment: I'd love to help on an SDE question but your code is very messy. You're using Subscripts which isn't a good idea, you're being a bit excessive on 1000 digit precision, you're using a lot of greek characters, line breaks which didn't paste properly and you do `x -> 10000 x` which is confusing. Can you give us the final SDE to solve after everything has been properly evaluated or a shorter, cleaner version of your code?

Comment: I reformatted your code and corrected several syntax errors that may have arisen when you transferred the code to StackExchange.  I did not, however, correct two coding errors.  You have `γa` where I believe you meant `γ*a`, and ` /. arr` should be inside `NDSolve`, not outside, so that it assigns values to `x`, `y`, and `z` before solving the ODEs. With these corrections, I was able to generate your two plots.  However, I am no expert in `ItoProcess`, so I cannot help you there.  Please check your `ItoProcess` arguments, because I may have copied them incorrectly due to Unicode issues.

Comment: Thank you , guys, for your comments and editing the code, really appreciate the help. I'm such a typo and now still struggling with getting plot of pertubated system since I don't know how to use ItoProcess properly.

Comment: It is not clear what is arr?

Comment: Sorry I changed it to stablePoint but not everywhere in a code, fixed it. It is the stable point, or initial conditions for NDSolve{ v[0]=x, tau[0]=y, tl[0]=z}

Comment: `{x, y, z}` are undefined in your  `ItoProcess`.  I believe that you need `{x, y, z} /. stablePoint`.  Unfortunately, this change leads to `General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation. >>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in my comment, `{x, y, z}` must be defined in order for `ItoProcess` to work.  Even then, the solution is unstable for the parameters chosen in the question.  Stable parameters are, for instance, `sigma = .01` and a `RandomFunction` step size of `0.1`.  In all, the modified code

```
sigma = .01;
trajectory = 
  ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]v[t] == (a*δ*to[t] - a*δ*τ[t] - 
        b*τ[t]*(10000 v[t])^κ) \[DifferentialD]t + sigma \[DifferentialD]w[t],
    \[DifferentialD]to[t] == ((bifP*α)/Ocean + (γ*a)/Ocean τ[t] - (γ*a + c)/
        Ocean to[t]) \[DifferentialD]t + sigma \[DifferentialD]w[t], 
    \[DifferentialD]τ[t] == (bifP β/Land*(1 - (10000 v[t])^κ/M) + ((γ + μ)*
        a)/Land to[t] - ((γ + μ)*a + c)/Land τ[t] - (b*μ)/Land (10000 v[t])^κ*τ[t]) 
        \[DifferentialD]t + sigma \[DifferentialD]w[t]},
    {v[t], to[t], τ[t]}, {{v, to, τ}, {x, y, z} /. stablePoint}, t, 
        w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]];
 ans = RandomFunction[trajectory, {0, time, .1}];
 ListLinePlot[ans, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

This can be compared with the corresponding noise-free solution obtained from `NDSolve`.

[image]

**Addendum**

An alternative way to display the results is

```
ListPointPlot3D[ans["Values"], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> Automatic,
    PlotStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> 300 , AxesLabel -> {Style["V", Large], 
    Style["Tl", Large], Style["To", Large], ImageSize -> 500, Axes -> True}]
```

[image]

which can be compared with the noise-free `ParametricPlot3D` mentioned in the question.

[image]

Comment: bbgodfrey, thank you soooooo much!!!!!!!!!! You made my day, seriously, thank you!

Comment: I hope you remain active in Mathematica.SE! I suggest: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Ok, I hope to stay active and even useful here :) 2) I don't have enough reputation to vote the answer up, but did accepted it.

Comment: A year ago, my situation on this site was no different from yours.  It is amazing how much a person can learn asking and answering questions.  Thanks for accepting the answer.  Best wishes.

Comment: Thank you, very inspiring! One more question. I am trying to get 3D plot so I can observe cycles and see what happens according to the noise intensity, by smth like this: Plot3D[trajectory, {t, time}]  or , which doesn't work.  How do you work

Comment: With the `RandomFunction` named `ans` (for instance), time series for the three functions can be extracted using `ans["Values"]` and plotted using any of several 3D list plots.  I chose the one that gave a curve similar to that from `ParametricPlot3D` and added it to the answer.

Comment: Haven't noiticed the new plots before..Thank you very much.

Comment: You can superimpose the two new plots using `Show`, if you wish.  If you do, give them different colors and list the parametric plot first to pick up its labels.